# DNN library is not found

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

This was asked here
[How to solve Conv1D DNN library is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921382/how-to-solve-conv1d-dnn-library-is-not-found)
but the answer does not solve my problem. I am using cuda toolkit 11.2 and cudnn 8.1, but I still get this error.

Running in vscode, using a fresh tf environment.
The library load path appears to include cudnn

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib::/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/

I tried setting CUDA_HOME to CONDA_PREFIX, and that did not solve the problem.

I remember finding a procedure for installing tensorflow that included instructions for setting the cuda path, but I cannot find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Addition: I also tried setting CUDNN_PATH to $CONDA_PREFIX, and also to $CONDA_PREFIX/lib , but this did not work.

Additional info:
OS: POP OS (ubuntu 22.04)

conda version 23.1.0

relevant env info:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/mia_envNew/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/lib:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/lib::/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/

CUDA_HOME=/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf

PATH=/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin:/home/amw/anaconda3/condabin:/home/amw/.local/bin:/home/amw/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/amw/anaconda3

CONDA_PREFIX_2=/home/amw/anaconda3/envs/tf

CONDA_PREFIX_3=/home/amw/anaconda3

Update: I reinstalled cudnn and cuda_toolkit with
mamba install cudatoolkit cudnn

This appeared to solve the problem, until I rebooted. Then the problem returned. I set the env variable, and cannot see what has changed.

Update: it stopped working again (I do not know why) and even reinstalling tensorflow, cuda etc it still does not work.

> print("Num GPUs Available: ",len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

outputs:

> Num GPUs Available:  1

but when I write python code in spyder, vscode, or jupyter, I still get

> DNN library is not found

.

Comment: Are you using linux or wsl? For me on on linux, I just created a conda environment and included the cudnn library. I think you'll have to start from scratch and say precisely which packages you've installed and which conda distribution you're using. Note here you can find information about the additional env variables, but they aren't necessary for every installation mode. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip